# Access a child paragraph content with XPath

Tags: php, xpath

HTML:

```
<div class="b-list-fact__item-explanation js-fact-explanation">
    <p>Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1</p>
    <p>Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 </p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to access the text inside paragraphs and to combine all `p`'s into one string.

Was trying with a bunch of variations like:

PHP (running on 7.1.11):

```
    $html = file_get_contents('https://...');
    $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);

    $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
    $facts = $finder->query("//a[contains(@class, normalize-space('b-list-fact__item-text'))]");
    $long_fact = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'b-list-fact__item-explanation js-fact-explanation')]/p");

    foreach ($facts as $key => $fact) {
            $fact_description = $long_fact[$key]->textContent;
            $fact = trim($fact->textContent);
            $dataArr[] = str_replace("\n", " ", $fact);
            array_push($dataArr, $fact_description);
    }
```

`$long_fact = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'b-list-fact__item-explanation js-fact-explanation')]/p");`

`$long_fact = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'b-list-fact__item-explanation js-fact-explanation')]//p[1]");`

`$long_fact = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'b-list-fact__item-explanation js-fact-explanation')]/p/text()");`

```
if($long_fact->length)
        {
            var_dump($long_fact[0]->textContent);
        }

if($$long_fact->length)
        {
            var_dump($long_fact->textContent);
        }

if($$long_fact->length)
        {
            var_dump($long_fact->nodeValue);
        }
```

And like 30 other variations...

I'm totally lost as to why this can happen, other variations which don't include `p` tags are working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ptext = $finder->query('//div[contains(@class, "b-list-fact__item-explanation js-fact-explanation")]/p');
$paragraphs = [];
foreach ($ptext as $paragraph) {
    $paragraphs[] = $paragraph->textContent;
}
$combined = implode("\n", $paragraphs);
```

Alternatively just:

```
$ptext = $finder->query('//div[contains(@class, "b-list-fact__item-explanation js-fact-explanation")]')
    ->item(0)->textContent;
```

Comment: Now it says: `string(72) "   " `

Comment: I think that this is due to the fact that we you didn't access the `p` inside the div and now we're trying to access the text value of the div itself? I've faced the same issue already.

Comment: This site I was doing tests on has it's `<p>` tags inside a `data-html` attribute of a span which I didn't see when viewed the source code with Chrome Dev Tools. Your code works, thanks for helping out!